# Can VGA passthrough support more than one VM instance?

Tags: linux, video, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu

There are lots of guides out there that walk you through setting up VGA passthrough using Linux KVMs and QEMU.  But I was wondering...

Is it possible to have the same video card passed through to multiple VMs at the same time?  I am guessing no, but I'd really like to have both screens available to my VMs instead of having to dedicate one to a particular screen, or having to shut the guest down to reconfigure the video when I want to switch.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/369368/vga-passthrough-and-desktop-virtualization) has already been asked but that was 5 years ago and I'm wondering if the situation has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this if your video card supports it, which in almost all cases it won't.

Most video cards are designed to only be able to handle one OS talking to them at a time. So you can give the card to the host OS (and then only the host OS can use it). Or you can (with the aid of an IOMMU) give the entire graphics card exclusively to a single VM, and then that VM can use it, but the host OS can't and nor can any other VM. If you could somehow try to give the card to multiple VMs at once neither would work properly, because the guest OSes would both be trying to talk to the card at once. From the perspective of a single guest OS it would be as if the graphics card was continually mysteriously doing things you didn't ask it to.

The exception to all this is if the video card explicitly supports hardware virtualization, so that it can present multiple different views of itself to each VM, and each VM thinks it is seeing a complete graphics card of its own. For instance [this AMD press release](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/amd-reveals-worlds-2016feb01.aspx) describes a set of graphics cards which have this feature and can present GPU acceleration to multiple VMs at once.